# I want to access the data obtained after cleaning, and then store it in another data fram

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv which contains come invalid and null values. I stored whole data in a data frame using pandas library in jupyter and accessed data using columns and replaced with required values. while i access data after replacing its showing previous missing data.

```
variable["Emp_ID"]=variable["Emp_ID"].replace(["%^^^%", "---","Texas", "Cricket"], np.nan)
```

The above replaces the missing data in "Emp_ID" column with NaN values. But when I access the data its showing previous missing data.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Also, if you are using `pd.read_csv`, you can use the `na_values` parameter to define what strings represent `NaN` values when you're reading in the data.

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv(r"c://users/kishore/AI_Hub/Raw_Data.csv",engine="python") . Then used --->df["Emp_ID"].unique to find different types of values and then iused------>["Emp_ID"]=df["Emp_ID"].replace(["%^^^%", "---","Texas", "Cricket"], np.nan) . it replaced all invalid data with NaN values. When I accessed the column its showing previous data ...

Comment: The data that you're using seems to be on your own local drive. One way to make the example reproducible would be to use code to define a dataframe including some example records. Guideline on how to create a minimal, reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes data is in my own local drive

Comment: now that error is fixed..

Comment: @vald D........now that error is fixed.. .. I am accessing each column and getting all types of values using variable["Emp_ID"].unique #which gets all values in Emp_ID column, which showed all employee ids which also contains "%^^^%", "---","Texas", "Cricket" as employee id's  these are to be  fixed                                                                       then using replace keyword variable["Emp_ID"]=variable["Emp_ID"].replace(["%^^^%", "---","Texas", "Cricket"], np.nan) this replaced all the invali(%^^^%", "---","Texas", "Cricket) values...

Comment: @Vald C ......but after accessing first column I cant able to access another column. when I am trying to access variable["Salary"].unique which is another column its showing------> KeyError: 'Salary..... but salary column is there...'